# MVC4 Facebook and multiple subdomains

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, single-sign-on

I have currently 4 sites eventually will be closer to 100 (i'm developing a web based game) I have the main site (i.e www.domain.com) and then sub domains for each server (ie s1.domain.com s2.domain.com)

I'm used to the old membership apis which I can do this with simple forms auth and machine keys but Facebook is eluding me. I have a developers account and my app id and all that good stuff.

my goal is user hits WWW site logs in with face book pulls data from database to know which servers they have played on in past (if they have played before) then sends them to the server of choice retaining the Facebook auth. I know its possible I've seen at least one other game do it (evony) but I cannot find any information on how to implement it with mvc4.

does anyone know how to accomplish this or have links to a howto/blog/etc I've searched Google and so far all I can come up with for single-sign-on is the old ways of the membership provider.

many thanks in advance